# Google Admin Console use old page token with new auth token

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-api-explorer

I am accessing Google Directory API to list all ChromeOS devices with maxResults set to 100 and pageToken to fetch the next page. Once the token expires, I refresh the token and try to continue with the page where i was stopped previously using old page token. I get 400 error code.
Can any one let me know how can i resume to fetch the results once the token is renewed?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/list is the API

Comment: Have you tried using the [refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) so your sessions continues after the previous access tokens expires?

Comment: i have tried using the refresh token but still the same error